# Intersection of an infinite amount of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider a set $S = \{S_1, S_2, S_3, \dots\}$, where $S_i = \{i, i + 1, i + 2, \dots\}$.

What is the intersection of all of the sets in $S$?

Is the intersection even defined?  If it is, I'm pretty sure it should be the empty set.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would the intersection not be defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the set $S_{n+1}$ does not contain $n$, so $n\notin\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}S_i$

This is true for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ thus $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}S_i=\emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens when you take the intersection of $S_i$ with $S_{i+1}$. This will help considerably.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Your intersection is asking for an ever higher natural number. If such a natural number, belonging to ALL given sets, did exist, call it $n$, it wouldn't belong to the next set, $S_{n+1}$. Contradiction.